# How do I access a dynamic 2D array from an object which is passed to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, argument-passing, dynamic-arrays

I am a beginner in C++ so I am not sure if this is possible. I want to know if I can access a dynamic 2D array from an object which is passed to a function. Here is the simplified code:

Class A:

```
class A {
public:

   A(int length, int width) {
       // initializes the 2d array
   }

   int** getArray() { return array2d;}

   int getLength() { return length;}

   int getWidth() { return width;}

private:

   int** array2d;
   int length, width;
};
```

Class B:

```
#include "A.h"
class B {
public:

   B() {}

   void print(A* a) {

      int** temp = a->getArray();  // ERROR HERE

      for (int i = 0; i < a->getLength(); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < a->getWidth(); j++)
              cout << temp[i][j] << endl;
      }
   }

private:

   int** array2d;
};
```

Main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    A a = new A(15,15);
    B b = new B();

    b->print(a);
}
```

I keep getting this error: `Error   13  error C2086: 'int **A::array2d' : redefinition`.

I am not sure if I am passing the 2D array correctly. I am open to all suggestions. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: What is the full source for your files?

Comment: @Smith_61 What do you mean by full source? If you mean all the source code then its too complex and lengthy so I simplified the problem as an example in the code above

Comment: As in the entire code required to replicate the error. We can't debug what we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think i found the problem, the error number suggests that you are redefining something and i think that it is the name of `array2d`, because in both class you are using the same name. Hopefully changing the name will help you. 
And i also recommend you to change the name of parameter `a` in function `void print(A* a)` to `void print(A* objA)`, maybe problem is here.